# Is it possible to dynamic create the Kibana visualization from the API call?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana

I am very new to Kibana, and I can create the visualizations in the Kibana and add them to the dashboard. If I want to embed them to my website, I need to click on `Share`, `Embed code`, `Copy iFrame code` and paste it to the html. Is it possible complete the whole flow without Kibana website and do them by the API and according to the user's demand (or filter)?

For example, the simple dataset for the temperature history in the elasticsearch:

```
location timestamp    temperature
A        Jul.1 11:00  18
A        Jul.1 17:00  20
A        Jul.1 23:00  22
A        Jul.2 5:00   24
A        Jul.2 11:00  18
A        Jul.2 17:00  20
A        Jul.2 23:00  22
B        Jul.1 11:00  32
B        Jul.1 17:00  29
B        Jul.1 23:00  27
B        Jul.2 5:00   27
B        Jul.2 11:00  32
B        Jul.2 17:00  29
B        Jul.2 23:00  27
```

In our website, user could view different embeded visualization by

1. select for location A only, and display it by bar chart (temperature history)
2. select for location A and B both, select the time range for the past 2 months, and display it by line chart (temperature history)
3. For advanced requirement, user can choose to display in pie chart, area chart or heat map,...,etc.

Is it possible to achieve it by the Kibana? How can I do them for the whole flow?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using Kibana but you can use the Elasticsearch Search API for same as Kibana also use the Search API (DSL query) for getting data from Elasticsearch.

You can follow below steps:

1. Create an Elasticsearch DSL query based on requirement.
2. Execute Elasticsearch query using Search API.
3. Render the data into your custom UI. There are various libraries available for chart citation so you can use any one of them.

For your first usecase, you can use simple `term` query and get data from Elasticsearch for specific location.

```json
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "location ": {
        "value": "A"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For your second usecase, you can use `range` query for filter and then aggregation for getting value.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I understand the query on the elasticsearch. I thought Kibana is the tool for generating the visualization or dashboard, but it cannot generate them dynamically (by API or automatically). Am I right? So, what is the use case for the Kibana?

Comment: You are right that Kibana is the tool for generating the visualization or dashboard but it is  tightly couple with Elasticsearch. So Kibana dont expose any API for generating dashboard or visulaization in external UI. You can create kibana dashboard and use it as embedded html. You can consider Elasticsearch as DB and Kibana as UI where you can generate dashboard and visulzation using Elasticsearch data.

Comment: How about using Grafana? Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: @JamesFu I am not sure about Grafana as never worked on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new visualizations without the UI by uploading saved objects. However the structure and possibilities might be limited using this approach.
The iframe code usually refers a specific Kibana Endpoint / Visualization or Dashboard URL.
After creating a new visualization using the Saved Objects upload you also know the ID that is necessary to put it into the iframe.
Didn't test it myself but this should work.

Comment: My goal is to create the different visualization from the website (embed in part of our website). If we have thousands of location, we don't have create them in advanced. Is it possible?